# Metamask QR scanning on Android not working

Tags: android, blockchain, metamask, nft, ethers.js

I have a project where users can mint an NFT using their wallet. The NFT contract is deployed on the Gnosis Chain. I am able to successfully mint the NFT when using

- MetaMask on a Desktop browser
- Opening the link on Android & iPhone then using the Metamask app
- Scanning the QR code from the desktop browser on Metamask iPhone app

But the only issue is that when I scan the QR code on the Android Metamask app then minting it on the brower throws the error:

```
Error: missing revert data in call exception;
claim.tsx:145
Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethe
rs.org/v5-errors-CALL EXCEPTION ]
(data="Ox",
transaction=
{
  "from""Ox2...",
  "to": "0x2...",
  "data": "0x9..."
  "accessList":null
},
error=
{
  "code": -32000,
  "message": "Unexpected token 'i', "\invalid project id\n\" is not valid JSON"
},
code=CALL EXCEPTION,
version=providers/5.7.2)
```

It's very unusual since it works on all the other devices & methods except when **scanning the QR on Android** Metamask or Coinbase or any other wallet.

I'm also getting this Infura error in the browser console:
[image]

Maybe it's a Metamask issue then again it doesn't work on Coinbase wallet QR scanning either.